# Pass object to URL search params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass this object to url search params:

```
const obj = {
 mb_brand: car.base,
 mb_factor: car.factor,
 mb_type: car.type
}
```

I have function to set params:

```
const setQuery = (key, value) => {
        let obj_url = new URL(window.location.href);
        let params = obj_url.searchParams;
        params.set(key, value);

        Router.push({
            pathname: obj_url.pathname,
            search: obj_url.search
        });
    }
```

And what I tried so far is:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(obj).length ; i++){
   setQuery(Object.keys(obj)[i], Object.values(obj)[i])
}
```

But it just set 1 parameter not 3.

```js
const obj = {
  mb_brand: 'blah',
  mb_factor: 'blah',
  mb_type: 'blah'
}


const setQuery = (key, value) => {
  let obj_url = new URL(window.location.href);
  let params = obj_url.searchParams;
  params.set(key, value);

  /*Router.push({
      pathname: obj_url.pathname,
      search: obj_url.search
  });*/

  console.log(obj_url.search)
}


for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  setQuery(Object.keys(obj)[i], Object.values(obj)[i])
}
```

But it set just last param.

I want to see this result on url:

> localhost/index?mb_brand=blah&mb_factor=blah&?mb_type=blah

Comment: Shouldn't you only push to the router once you're done modifying the url, rather than with each param addition within your loop?

Comment: @KevinB because this function also use for single time, not only loop. I set query for example on click on one input.

Comment: Right, but, your code loops. And pushes to the router after every change. so it always just does one before it navigates.

Comment: @KevinB well, now I want to know how can change this function to use for both condition, is it possible? or I need to create another function for loops

Comment: You'd need a different function, or you'd need to change both the function and everything that uses this existing function for just 1 param.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks I understand now, but still not figured out how can I store multiple params somewhere then just push that to url once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your `params` variable again and again because the `setQuery` is being called inside a loop, and overwriting the previous query param. Hence, only the last param is available. Define these variables outside of the `searchQuery`, so that the `for` loop can append the params to the same variable.

```
const obj = {
  mb_brand: 'blah',
  mb_factor: 'blah',
  mb_type: 'blah'
}

let obj_url = new URL(window.location.href);
let params = obj_url.searchParams;

const setQuery = (key, value) => {

  params.set(key, value);

  // console.log(obj_url.search)
}


for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  setQuery(Object.keys(obj)[i], Object.values(obj)[i])
}

/*Router.push({
          pathname: obj_url.pathname,
          search: obj_url.search
      });*/

console.log(params.toString());
```

Console output:

```
mb_brand=blah&mb_factor=blah&mb_type=blah
```

Comment: Thanks Actually your code not working in my project because I'm using reactjs but I understand your propose and logic, with some changes and edit in my real code is working fine, I moved out `obj_url` and `params` params outside my function and that helped! + in my code I should define new url in state inside useeffect

Comment: You can get this result: `mb_brand=blah&mb_factor=blah&mb_type=blah
` just by doing `new URLSearchParams({
  mb_brand: 'blah',
  mb_factor: 'blah',
  mb_type: 'blah'
})`

Answer (score -1):

You can directly build search params from an object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams:

```js
// Search parameters can also be an object
const paramsObj = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'bar'};
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsObj);

searchParams.toString();                 // "foo=bar&baz=bar"
searchParams.has('foo');                 // true
searchParams.get('foo');
```